Floppy disk will not work with fdisk
I was trying to make a partition on a floppy disk to where it would show up as /dev/sdb1 with fdisk (yes, I have used mkfs and similar tools) and when I use fdisk and then the device name, it just says "Operation not Supported"!
I have tried different floppy disks.

What sort of floppy disk? What did you try in MKFS or the other tools, so we know what not to suggest? Please EDIT your post to give us more information, including details of the system and devices you're working with, the exact and specific steps you've tried so far, etc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I assume you're using a USB floppy disk reader? Can you provide the exact output from fdisk when it shows this error?

Yes, you are "doing something wrong". A floppy should not have a partition table nor be partitioned. Those concepts were first and only applied to HDDs in MS-DOS when the IBM PC-XT model and MS-DOS 2.0 were introduced

You cannot partition a floppy disk (as in 3.5" or 5.25"). Consequently, fdisk won't touch it - works as designed.
